# Showing a function is contractive

Tags: analysis

This seems to simple of a question and thus I am doubting myself...

Show that the function $\dfrac{1}{2}x$ on $1\leq x \leq 5$ is contractive.

\begin{align}
|F(x) - F(y)| =& \left|\dfrac{1}{2}x -\dfrac{1}{2}y\right| \\
=& \dfrac{1}{2}|x -y| \\
\leq& \dfrac{1}{2}|x-y|
\end{align}

This should then be true for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ correct?

Now, what I don't know is how to find the best  value of $\lambda$ (I assume best means least value for $\lambda$) in the contractive mapping definition:
\begin{equation}
|F(x)-F(y)| \leq \lambda|x-y| 
\end{equation}

Let me know what you think, and any suggestions that you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|F(x)-F(y)|$ is always exactly $\frac12|x-y|$, it’s clear that $|F(x)-F(y)|\le\lambda|x-y|$ if and only if $\lambda\ge\frac12$.

Comment: Is $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{2}$ the best then as it is the smallest possible value for which the inequality holds? Is the question being stated for $1\leq x \leq 5$ superfluous?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: That’s right: *best* in this context means *smallest*, and $\frac12$ is clearly the smallest factor that works.